# VisualStudio 2010 setup project to InstallShield seamless transition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installshield

I just installed VS2013. As there is no longer the Setup Project, I installed InstallShield LE. I used integrated import wizard and hoped any newer build would automatically update older versions created with VS Setup project. Well, I used to alter the Product Version, which prompted me to alter the Product Code, and that was it. Now I thought this should work with InstallShield as well, so I updated the product version and manually generated the product code. I had the older application installed and tried to reinstall it with this new IS LE setup. And the result is: There are two applications installed, which have exactly the same name and path (it installed in the same directory), but different version. I can really see 2 programs with the same name in "Programs and Features". I checked the upgrade code, it is the same for both. What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally we were able to solve the problem. You need to place an entry to the Upgrades Path section. Oddly enough You need to do this manually and it's not done automatically by the IS import wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Check the installation type, i.e. per user or per machine. It must be the same for both versions, otherwise Windows Installer will skip removing the old versions and you will end up with both versions on your machine.

A [verbose log](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2545723) created when you install the new version should also be helpful, you can search for FindRelatedProducts and RemoveExistingProducts standard actions in it, to see why the old version is not removed.

Comment: Well in the VS2010 Setup Project, there was InstallAllUsers property, which was set to false. In the new (imported) IS LE project, there was (in the General Information section) the ALLUSERS option set to 1 (per-machine installation) . So I changed that to "", which should be per-user installation, but it didn't help. It still installs alongside the old version.

Comment: I will try the log and see if it is of any help. Then I'll let you know.

Comment: Well, in in the log I found this:
MSI (c) (5C:40) [13:04:01:320]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action 13:04:01: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 13:04:01: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (c) (5C:40) [13:04:01:321]: FindRelatedProducts: current install is per-user.  Related install for product '{7CF44E5C-B8DB-4BF0-8759-061FC61CD808}' is per-machine.  Skipping...
Action ended 13:04:01: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.

Comment: So I uninstalled the old application and installed it for all users (VS2010 Setup let's U choose during the installation) and installed it again, now it says:
MSI (c) (EC:5C) [12:54:45:283]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action 12:54:45: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 12:54:45: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 12:54:45: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.

But it still installs alongside the old version.

Comment: Ans as for the RemoveExistingProducts:
MSI (s) (50:14) [13:14:58:253]: Doing action: RemoveExistingProducts
Action 13:14:58: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
Action start 13:14:58: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action ended 13:14:58: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 1.

Comment: It is strange, if the applications have the same upgradecode FindRelatedProducts action should detect the old version installed, especially since it detects it when is installed per-user. Can you check the upgradecode for both projects (in the log too)? Maybe a bug in the VS extension lead to generating a new one or something else happened during the installation.

Comment: Upgrade codes do match in the project settings for the old and the new project. I looked in the installation log and searched for "UpgradeCode". It finds 4 matches and all of them match the upgrade code in the project settings. But what does the FindRelatedProducts return value 1 indicate? I guess it should print the matches if any, am I right?

Comment: Return value 1 means the action ended without any errors, that is good. What I don't understand is why is not finding the old version. I assume you don't have different install languages for them? i.e. check ProductLanguage property in the log.

Comment: Well since it is imported, this shouldn't be a problem, unless there is a bug in the wizard, and I checked that as well. In the VS 2010 setup, there is a property called Localization, which is set to English (United States), in IS setup there is Setup Language option, which is set to the same value. I suppose these two are the corresponding properties here. In the log there is a line: Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033.

Comment: I could send you the log files for both installations (the old one and the new one) if you would be so kind as to take a look and see if there's anything suspicious.

Comment: sure, send them to be, bogdan at advancedinstaller dot com is my address. Also send me the logs of the per-user installation, the one that gets detected but skipped because the install types are different.